# No module named parse

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am getting the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kiran.py", line 5, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
ImportError: No module named parse
```

I have tried using

```
pip install -U websocket
pip install parse
```

but still error is coming

Comment: Use the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), not the Python 3 documentation. `urllib.parse` is **specific to Python 3 only**. Or switch to Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use code designed for Python 3, in Python 2.

The functionality of the Python 3 `urllib.parse` module is found in the [`urlparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) in Python 2, so you want to adjust your code. You do not need to install other packages.

However, if you are following a tutorial or copying code from the web, you need to switch to Python 3 instead. There *will* be other issues with the code not running on Python 2.

Comment: i am using in Python 2

Comment: Yes, I know you are. That's why you get the error, you are using Python 3 source code in Python 2.

Comment: i will install python3 let me check

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: @KiranKumarReddy: that's an entirely different question.